# How to change the position of the "You can also login with" in Parse Login view controller

Tags: ios, parse-platform, loginview

Here is the screen shot link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6gcsxxt0yrrxial/Screen%20Shot%202014-08-26%20at%2018.42.10.png?dl=0
Now, the "you can also login with" and "Do not have account yet?" textFields are dislocated. Is there any way I can move those words up?

Comment: Yes u can. If you are using a XIB, just change the positions, if the view are created programatically, then change the Y position of the objects in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you created a subclass of `PFLoginViewController`, you should override `didLayoutSubviews` to adjust the frames of the elements on screen.

What you are looking for should be the property `externalLoginLabel` [2] of the `PFLoginView`

[1] https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#ui-login/iOS
[2] https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFLogInView.html#//api/name/externalLogInLabel